# Directory traversal Issue c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, testing, veracode

I have a C# application where I am uploading an image and storing it in a directory. I am checking the file so to allow one image formats before uploading. When I am testing my module with Veracode it shows Directory traversal Issues CWE ID 73.. I am not sure if its correct because I am checking the file type before uploading

My code for uploading file is below

```
if (filebigimage.HasFile)
{
   if ((((((this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/gif") | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/pjpeg")) | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")) | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpg")) | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png")) | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/bmp"))
                        {
                           // string StrBigImageName = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offerImagePath"] + "BigImages/Temp/");
                            if ((this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/gif"))
                            {
                                strBigimgformat = ".gif";
                                objBigImgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif; 
                            }
                            else if ((this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/pjpeg") | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg") | (this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpg"))
                            {
                                strBigimgformat = ".jpg";
                                objBigImgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;

                            }
                            else if ((this.filebigimage.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png"))
                            {
                                strBigimgformat = ".png";
                                objBigImgFormat = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png; 
                            }
                            filebigimage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offerImagePath"] + "BigImages/Temp/") + filebigimage.FileName);
                            strbigimagename = filebigimage.FileName;
                        } 
}
```

Then I am storing the values into the database and getting the id number of the row and creating a filename and moving this file from temp to main folder

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offerImagePath"]
+ "BigImages/Temp/" + strbigimagename)))
{
   File.Move(Server.MapPath("../" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offerImagePath"] + "BigImages/Temp/"
+ strbigimagename), Server.MapPath("../" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["offerImagePath"] + "BigImages/" + strorderid + "_bigimage" + strBigimgformat));
}
```

Please let me know whats wrong with it ... Is it vulnerable to Directory traversal Issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using user input (filebigimage.FileName) as part of a file name on your server.  This is a security risk.  You should come up with some other method for naming the files.

Comment: i am using a sanitizing function now

Comment: private static string MakeValidFileName( string name )
{
   string invalidChars = Regex.Escape( new string( Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() ) );
   string invalidReStr = string.Format( @"[{0}]+", invalidChars );
   return Regex.Replace( name, invalidReStr, "_" );
}..........Will it help in solving the issue

Comment: Even if you sanitize the input you may still run into collision issues (e.g. different users use the same file name).  Instead you might use a database row ID or a GUID for saving files to your server; store the user's original filename elsewhere in your database so that you can recover it if needed.

Comment: Problem here is not collision its directory traversal issue

Comment: I think the point Rogers making is that you shouldn't be using the users file name, by all means sanitize it and store it to display to the user in an admin or something but dear god just replace the filename with a random string or guid before storing it. Traversal issue solved.